# Memgraph with Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, memgraphdb

Does anybody use Memgraph as a graph database with the Spring Data Neo4j API through the Neo4j java driver?
Would be interested in hearing your experiences. Thanks!

Memgraph advertises as a drop-in replacement for Neo4j. Quickly spinning up memgraph/memgraph-platform in Docker and trying to connect from Spring Data Neo4j fails with lots of Exceptions though.

Comment: I think Memgraph is playing a bit fast and loose with the claim of being a "drop-in replacement for Neo4j". You cannot use everything in the Neo4j ecosystem with Memgraph. And they do not even support the full Cypher language.